# generating a histogram for survey weighted data

Tags: r

I am asking this question in working with complex survey data set that has weights for each observation. When I generate a histogram of the continuous variable (number of conditions), these are unweighted observations:

```
    hist(data$number_prev_services)
```

Is there an appropriate function for generating histogram with survey weights, accounting for survey design?